# How to write a regex matching a list of number not containg two same numbers

Tags: java, regex

I trying to write a regexp mathing a list of numbers such that any two elements of that are distinct. I'm gonna use it to validate a textbox field on a `java jsf`-webpage. For instance:

```
1, 23,  12 // ok
1, 1, 2, 45  // fail 
1, 2, 4, 6, 7 // ok
1, 2, 3, 3   //fail
```

I wrote the regex `^[1-9](|[0-9])+(|\s+)(|\s+,\s+[1-9](|[0-9])+(|\s+))+$`, but it matches both 2 and 4 examples I provided. How can I correct that?

Comment: @TheLostMind I provided these inputs just as an example.

Comment: Why don't you split them and add then to a Set?

Comment: @TheLostMind Just because I don't want to add any garbage data provided by user to the Set

Comment: This is not the case for regular expressions.

Comment: @St.Antario - Well, if you are *using this data*, then it is not *garbage*. Next, this case is not *suited* for regex.

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Why?

Comment: @St.Antario regular expressions are typically the tool for easier problems. The code with regex here will be unreadable, much more unreadable, than written just with `input.split(",\\s*")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the below [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) based regex.

```
^(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)\d+(?:,\s+\d+)+$
```

`(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)` at the start asserts that there wouldn't be any duplicate numbers on the strings we are going to match. `\b` called word boundary which matches between a word character and a non-word character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/3)

Turn the `+` after the above non-capturing group to `*` if you want to match also the strings which contain only one number.

```
^(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)\d+(?:,\s+\d+)*$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/6)

Java regex would be,

```
"^(?!.*\\b(\\d+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b)\\d+(?:,\\s+\\d+)+$"
```

**Example:**

```
String[] s = {"1, 23,  12", "1, 2, 4, 6, 7", "1, 1, 2, 45", "1, 2, 3, 3", "1, 2, 1"};
for (String i: s)
{
    System.out.println(i.matches("(?!.*\\b(\\d+)\\b.*\\b\\1\\b)\\d+(?:,\\s+\\d+)+"));
}
```

Output:

```
true
true
false
false
false
```

Comment: No, it doesn't what I'm looking for. `1, 2, 1` is passed.

Comment: Is it possible to also match the strings containing any number of space symbol before the commas?

Comment: just turn the inbetween `\s+` to `\s*`, see https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/11 or for spaces before the commas, see this https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/12

Comment: @vks he means the spaces before the commas.

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*$
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/4